# Is there a .NET REST framework that meets these requirements?

Tags: .net, rest

We just started a greenfield project. A part of requirements is to provide application server Api as REST services. I found few ways to do it using **OpenRasta**, **Windsor WcfFacility**. From what I see on Web is not much information on this topic. I'm looking for a framework with support of:

1. non intrusive api
2. security
3. interface versionning
4. fluent configuration api

What is your framework of choice and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For openrasta:

1. The API is as non-intrusive as you can, with POCO resouces and POCO handlers.
2. Supports HTTP Digest authentication, and provides interceptors for role-based authentication. Plugging in a custom solution would be quite easy, and if you run on asp.net you can use that too.
3. Interface versioning in terms of ReST APIs is a bad idea (as versioning interfaces, URIs etc is inherently not restful, and breaks a multitude of scenarios). You should instead either do media type versioning if you want to support multiple media types, or do the more restful way and make one media type versionable and extensible.
4. Yeap, we got that. :)